# Bool object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
is_shooting = []
is_shooting.append(False)
ShootWeapon(0)    

def ShootWeapon(wep_num):
        is_shooting[wep_num] = True
```

I'm getting a weird error where python is telling me that bool objects don't support item assignment and I'm not sure why.

Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\GitHub\SuperNova\Main.py", line 141, in <module>
    main.InputEvents()
  File "C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\GitHub\SuperNova\Main.py", line 133, in InputEvents
    }[event.key]()
  File "C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\GitHub\SuperNova\Main.py", line 129, in <lambda>
    pg.K_a : lambda : Weapons.Weapons.ShootWeapon(0),
  File "C:\Users\Kian\Desktop\GitHub\SuperNova\Weapons.py", line 107, in ShootWeapon
    is_shooting[wep_num] = True
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: That code won't generate that error (after reordering so that ShootWeapon is defined before it's used).  You're going to need to construct an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the full error traceback, so that we can point out where you've set something to a bool.

Comment: Please include your full traceback; it sounds as if you rebound the `is_shooting` global somewhere else however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somewhere *else* in your code you assigned a boolean directly to the `is_shooting` global:

```
>>> is_shooting = [False]
>>> is_shooting[0] = True
>>> is_shooting = True
>>> is_shooting[0] = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support item assignment
```

You'll have to search through your code to find out where you do so.

Comment: Thank you I found the error it was in a completely different function than the one I was looking at. The function it error-ed out in wasn't in the trace but I found it. Thank you for the help!